# Custom content search (crawler) sent old indexed ids

Tags: content-search, indexing

I have a completely custom search crawler that pushes data to Algolia. If I run the full reindex it works great. When trying to use a onPublishEndAsync strategy I see the first item come in I publish get sent to Algolia. Then if I save something else the previous item AND the new item get sent to Algolia. It keeps expanding from there.

What's weird is that it seems to me Sitecore is sending the list of unique IDs to the index. It should realize that I previously indexed the items and not to send them.

I've tried to replicate the SolrProvider and raise events. I've setup indexing:start, indexing:end, indexing:committing, indexing:committed. Also using a CommitPolicyExecutor to specify when an item was added to the index and when the index was committed.'

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the eventQueue.

I'm on Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 160729).

The code base is originally here without my changes, https://github.com/dharnitski/Sitecore.Algolia/. I raised an issue there but the author hasn't been active in some time.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not much clear. Please rephrase your sentences so that everybody can get exactly what you wanted to ask.